# my ASP.NET GridView does not bind correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, binding

I have an ASP.NET GridView supposed to exec a SQL Query.
The query is never executed so I strongly suspect there is a binding issue somewhere.

Here is the aspx code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="i_sdsGv" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXX %>"

              SelectCommand="INCOHERENT QUERY IN ORDER TO TRIGGER AN EXCEPTION"
            SelectCommandType="Text"

       <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="MyTableId" QueryStringField="MyTableId" />
            </SelectParameters>


     </asp:SqlDataSource>

    ...


      <asp:GridView ID="i_gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="MyTableId"
                    DataSourceID="i_sdsGv" OnRowDataBound="i_gvOptionChoix_RowDataBound">
                    <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">                              
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="i_tbName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MyTableName") %>' />                           
                            </ItemTemplate>
                    </Columns>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>   
               NO ROWS TO DISPLAY
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
     </asp:GridView>
```

I am 100% sure that if the query string is inexact, an exception is triggered.
In my case, no exception is triggered so the query is not executed.
I get the  NO ROWS TO DISPLAY text.

The only obvious binding that I can think about is between the DataSource and the GridView. It does look OK to me.

So I would suspect an issue with :

```
DataKeyNames="MyTableId" ?
```

My i_gvOptionChoix_RowDataBound method is empty at the moment but I think it does not matter at this time?

What am I missing so the app actually attempts to execute the query?
Thx in advance for your kind assistance

Comment: have you tracked it yet? put a breakpoint and track it carefully.

Comment: It's in the aspx code, not into the code behind code. So you can't put breakpoints there.
And I doubt it would have helped since if it is really a binding issue.

Comment: you are using SqlDataSource, bind it in your code behind and put a breakpoint there, clear your query in aspx and bind the query in your codebehind :) happy coding.